# diff between Jules and Jenkins

Tags: testing

I am trying to understand what is the difference between Jenkins and Jules ?
Is it only the version change?

researched on what is Jules and jenkins but did not find the correct solution

Answer (score 2):

Jules is based on Jenkins 2.0 standards, where you can setup builds using .jenkins file and have a fancy UI (looks better than Jekins).
Jules is only used in the Organization you are currently working in as a CICD Pipeline (based on my work experience). Jenkins has become an industry standard for CICD pipeline.